# IIS hosted WCF Service return HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have been searching for hours, but I could not find the solution. I will explain briefly.

I am learning WCF Services. I have just created a service and browse it. Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EmployeeServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeServiceBehaviour" name="EmployeeConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2005/EmployeeService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="IEmployeeConfiguration" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When browse it from Visual Studio there seems no problem. It works perfectly.

[image]

[image]

Second, I am trying to publish it on IIS. What I am doing is this:

I publish the service to a folder and add this service to IIS.

[image]

I select port 3006 as a port.

Below its config file. Note that I also changed port inside config to 3006

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EmployeeServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeServiceBehaviour" name="EmployeeConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3006/EmployeeService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="IEmployeeConfiguration" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I am waiting to run smoothly but:
[image]

[image]

IIS gives me a blank page from Chrome

[image]

And HTTP 400 Bad Request from Explorer

[image]

Lastly, if I remove address part from config file everything works well. But other confused thing is that, on my other computer after above scenario(address provided) I can reach the service. So, I really tired of searching why this is working on one computer and not working on another one. Could someone explain it to me?

I know it is a bit longer, but I have to explain it clearly.
Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue and I resolved it. It was a long time ago but I can find the document if no one answers you till then :)

Comment: @Alireza Thanks. I will appreciate you, If you provide it for me now. Because I couldn't find the answer anywhere and most likely you will forget this question soon :)

Comment: No I won't. Don't make me stay awake to find the solution ;-) It's 2 in the morning here and I'm sleepy

Comment: @Alireza  Ok. Sleep now :) and I am waiting to hear from you if no one answers

Comment: Merhaba! I think this is something deeper than just a service. Can you add a simple ASPX page and publish it to this new web site, then see if you can browse that page?

Comment: OK. Forget about my previous comment. The problem is after adding the `endpoint`, IIS can't find your `mex` (metadata exchange) path. I will be back

Comment: @alireza merhaba. If so how my other computer can browse it. I will try it although, but my computer is at home. I will let you know evening

Comment: I added the answer dear Osman and will be waiting to here from you tonight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According my searches, I should not provide an address.

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx)

> You must always use relative endpoint addresses for IIS-hosted service
> endpoints. Supplying a fully-qualified endpoint address (for example,
> localhost/MyService.svc) can lead to errors in the deployment of the
> service if the endpoint address does not point to the IIS-application
> that hosts the service exposing the endpoint. Using relative endpoint
> addresses for hosted services avoids these potential conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem:

Add this endpoint to your service:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

And change the `name` attribute of the `service` to your service class's full name:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeServiceBehaviour" 
    name="Namespace.EmployeeConfigurationClass">
```

Hope that is enough

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I have two computers one at work and one at home. Please note that, if I remove address part I can browse on both of them. If I provide address I can browse on only work computer, home computer gives responses above in my question. So, I suspect something like IIS setting.

Comment: We will fix it tonight :)

Comment: I hope so, thanks. I am searching HTTP 400 error on IIs

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking for it. It didn't work. But according my searches I should not provide an address. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx says:You must always use relative endpoint addresses for IIS-hosted service endpoints. Supplying a fully-qualified endpoint address (for example, http://localhost/MyService.svc) can lead to errors in the deployment of the service if the endpoint address does not point to the IIS-application that hosts the service exposing the endpoint. Using relative endpoint addresses for hosted services avoids these potential conflicts.

Comment: I don't know why this works for my one computer and not other, but I think it is better not to supply an address, so it will work for both computers. Thank you for helping Alireza

Comment: I didn't help at all, and I learned something from you. Make this comment of yours an answer for someone having the same problem in the future :)

Comment: Thanks for all Alireza:)

Comment: Please look my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874859/wcf-the-contract-name-imetadataexchange-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help. ive just spent over 2 hours trying to get this working. i use FF and its set as the default browser.

in FF it was adding a / on the end of my URL

```
http://services.tester.dev/VehicleFeedService.svc/
```

which returned a `NetworkError: 400 Bad Request`

however in IE or chrome, it doesnt put the / on the end and it works fine.

one thing to note.. even in FF which was giving me a 400 bad request, the `?wdsl` did work

```
http://services.tester.dev/VehicleFeedService.svc?wsdl
```

it appears that the / was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try fiddler and also try the svcTracer which may give you lot of debugging information on the top of it you can also use `includeExceptionDetailInFaults=true` flag on the server but its important to flag that its not always right to send this information to the client specially if client is an external entity. With this warning following is the hint how to use it.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
    ....
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    ....
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Happy debugging :)