# WCF, The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I am simply applying code from this article,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx

I did not change anything but after browsing from IIS I am getting

```
The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service CalculatorService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract
```

What may be wrong, I did just as the link. I searched for an answer. I can handle by adding

```
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

But I do not want to add this because when looking at the link msdn does not add. What is the error?

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host:                                        http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <!-- The mex endpoint is explosed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any official document stating the relation between `<serviceMetadata>` and `IMetadataExchange`.

Just this comment inside the example for [`<serviceMetadata>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex 
To expose the IMetadataExchange contract, you 
must enable the serviceMetadata behavior as demonstrated below -->
```

It says "You MUST", but no reference yet.

Comment: Yes, you are right ate least <serviceMetadata/> must be added as a serviceBehavior

Answer (score 6):

For learning it on your own try deleting the below statement and then check your service again.

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Finally Web.config file will look like this to complete it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration
        model introduced in .NET Framework 4 -->
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host:                                        http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <!-- The mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                    <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the metadata endpoint.

Here's what the endpoint config looks like:

```
<endpoint name="MyServiceMex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Here's a slightly more complete example that shows what the service config might look like:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyProject.Services.MyService">        
    <endpoint name="MyServiceEndpoint"
              contract="MyProject.Contracts.IMyService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" />
<!-- Expose your Metadata (MEX) endpoint too -->            
<endpoint name="MyServiceMex"
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Please look my updated question, I am using the same config as exist in the link