# "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a project for files upload and it is build like this:

I have a solution with several project in it some of them are:

1. WCF service
2. Class library for "Business Logic"
3. UI

When I am trying to upload filed greater then 1MB I'm getting this error:

"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Here is my code that uploads the file:

```
public string UploadFile(string serviceUrl,decimal maxFileSize, AttachmentFileParams fileParams, Stream file)
        {
            try
            {
                if (file.Length > (maxFileSize * 1024)) //maxFileSize is defined in KB and file.Length is in Bytes
                    return Serialization.ConvertToJson(new { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = Constants.Messages.MaxFileSizeExceeded + maxFileSize });

                string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/UploadFile", serviceUrl);
                string jsonFile = Serialization.ConvertToJson(fileParams);
                byte[] jsonFileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonFile);
                byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(jsonFileBytes.Length);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
                request.Method = "POST";

                byte[] bufferRead = new byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)jsonFileBytes.Length + file.Length))];
                int bytesReadCount;

                request.ContentLength = (long)len.Length + (long)jsonFileBytes.Length + file.Length;               

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {

                    requestStream.Write(len, 0, len.Length);

                    //*************************HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN*********************************//
                    requestStream.Write(jsonFileBytes, 0, jsonFileBytes.Length);
                    //*************************HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN*********************************//

                    while ((bytesReadCount = file.Read(bufferRead, 0, bufferRead.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(bufferRead, 0, bytesReadCount);
                    }

                    requestStream.Close();
                }

                HttpWebResponse resposne = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                string result = string.Empty;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resposne.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Serialization.ConvertToJson(new { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

I've tryied adding these configuration in the wcf service and the ui app web.config files:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>


//in the service config file there is also this:
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBroadcast360" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 textEncoding="utf-8" openTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="True">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None" />          
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I don't think it's related to a server issue because it happens even when I'm running it with VisualStudio on my local computer where I'm the admin.

Maybe I'm forgetting some configuratoin somewhere but I don't know where...

Comment: I'd a similar issue. In my server configuration file, I'd to include another wsHttpBinding configuration without a name, with maxReceivedMessageSize and the other properties with maximum value of 2147483647. The reason was, different from client, that you provide the binding and name, for server it uses a "default" binding, so the server side try to find a wsHttpBinding  without a name, as "default" configuration.
I don't know if is the same issue to you, but you can try it out, maybe can help.

Comment: I tryied you suggestion like this:
`<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 textEncoding="utf-8" openTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="True">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        ...
      </wsHttpBinding>`
But it didn't solve it...
Was that what you ment ?

Comment: Yes, and I have these lines for service behavior:
<behaviors><serviceBehaviors><behavior><dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>....

Comment: I found someone who said it might be because there is no `endpoint` related to this `binding` but I don't know how to set an `endpoint`...

Comment: It's a possibility. To set a endpoint you must include it in services, like this:
<system.serviceModel>....
    <services>
      <service name="NameForYourService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBroadcast360"
                  behaviorConfiguration="YouBehaviorConfiguration"
                  contract="YourContract"/>
      </service>

endpoint address can be left empty, or you can provide the full http path for your service

Comment: I've added your code: `<services>
      <service name="...">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBroadcast360"
                  behaviorConfiguration="AttachmentServiceBehavior"
                  contract="..."/>
      </service>
    </services>`
and I have this behavior: `<behavior name="AttachmentServiceBehavior">
          ...
        </behavior>`
But it tells me that: `There is no endpoint behavior named 'AttachmentServiceBehavior'.`

Comment: Below behaviors tag, you have two different configurations: endpointBehaviors and serviceBehaviors. As you're using 'AttachmentServiceBehavior' for endpoint, this behavior must be in endpointBehaviors.

Comment: I added this: `<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpointBehaviors">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>` but now I'm getting `400 Bad Request` when calling the service...

Comment: In your <service><endpoint> tag, are you providing any address? The address must be empty, or a relative path:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855068/iis-hosted-wcf-service-return-http-400-bad-request

Comment: I am working on this code with 2 other colleagues, and one of them told me that the address is set programmatically

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved it, and here is my code for the solution:

```
public class WCFClientProxy<IServiceContract> : ClientBase<IServiceContract> where IServiceContract : class
{
    public IServiceContract Instance
    {
        get { return base.Channel; }
    }
}

public string UploadFile(decimal maxFileSize, AttachmentFileParams fileParams, Stream file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.Length > (maxFileSize * 1024)) //maxFileSize is defined in KB and file.Length is in Bytes
            return Serialization.ConvertToJson(new { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = Constants.Messages.MaxFileSizeExceeded + maxFileSize });

        string jsonFile = Serialization.ConvertToJson(fileParams);
        byte[] jsonFileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonFile);
        byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(jsonFileBytes.Length);
        byte[] bufferRead = new byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)jsonFileBytes.Length + file.Length))];
        int bytesReadCount;

        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(len, 0, len.Length);
            stream.Write(jsonFileBytes, 0, jsonFileBytes.Length);

            while ((bytesReadCount = file.Read(bufferRead, 0, bufferRead.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(bufferRead, 0, bytesReadCount);
            }
            stream.Position = 0;
            WCFClientProxy<Attachment.Interfaces.IAttachmentService> proxy = new WCFClientProxy<Attachment.Interfaces.IAttachmentService>();
            return proxy.Instance.UploadFile(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Serialization.ConvertToJson(new { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Service configuration:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="XXX.Implementation.AttachmentService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
                  bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize"
                  contract="XXX.Interfaces.IAttachmentService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="higherMessageSize" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>

          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
     <handlers>
         <remove name ="WebDAV"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Client configuration:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>

        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>

          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:54893/AttachmentService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IAttachmentService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
                contract="XXX.Interfaces.IAttachmentService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of *how* you solved it. This appears to just be a code dump... what was the cause of the issue in your question, and what change to your code fixed the issue?

Comment: The answer is not helpful at all. Indeed it was just a code dump. I guess we have to do a diff on the before and after to find out what has been changed. Is it even worth the bother?